# Generate text up to certain number

Tags: url, text

So, I have a URL

```
sub.domain.com/tile/512/0/0/0.jpg?blablabla123
```

and I need `0/0/0.jpg` to go up to `6/43/43.jpg` 6 being the highest number for the first place, and 43 being the largest number to go up to on the middle and end numbers in the generated text.

Some examples:

`sub.domain.com/tile/512/0/0/0.jpg?blablabla123`

...

`sub.domain.com/tile/512/0/0/43.jpg?blablabla123`

`sub.domain.com/tile/512/0/1/0.jpg?blablabla123`

...

`sub.domain.com/tile/512/0/43/43.jpg?blablabla123`

`sub.domain.com/tile/512/1/0/0.jpg?blablabla123`

How can I do this and output to a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because I have a Python interpreter open...

```
for a in range(7):
    for b in range(44):
        for c in range(44):
            print('sub.domain.com/tile/512/%(a)d/%(b)d/%(c)d.jpg' % locals())
```

Save this to a file *make_urls.py* and then call like follows:

```
python make_urls.py > my_urls.txt
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a node.js script for that.

```
var fs = require('fs');

var stream = fs.createWriteStream('./urls.txt');
stream.once('open', function(fd) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j <= 43; j++) {
            for (var k = 0; k <= 43; k++) {
                stream.write('sub.domain.com/tile/512/' + i + '/' + j + '/' + k + '.jpg?blablabla123\n');
            }
        }
    }
    stream.end();
});
```